# Flutter Google Map On map rotate

Tags: flutter

How to listen to camera rotation event on flutter google map ?https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

I need this because I have custom marker (Image of a car) that I animate on a route. So the orientation is cacluated based on the route. So if the user rotates the camera even a bit, the orientation that I calculated would be wrong.

The solution could be adding an offset from the camera rotation angle (How far is it from the north alignment) But how do I get this offset value ? 
Is there a camera rotation event listener ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            // cameraPosition.bearing
          },
```